# How to imrpove maze solving algorithm for webcam images using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to find the solution on a maze without a pathfinding process, solely by using OpenCV. The idea is that, the algorithm finds the two parts of the maze by finding the contours. Then by applying dilation and erosion, I find the difference which has the solution. This works very well in a .png, however I want it to work it on a webcam picture so I made several modifications to the function. I'm a beginner in open cv so any help would be appreciated.

```py
filename1 = filename
      
img = cv2.imread(filename1)
    
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,filename+ ' 0. Maze.jpg'),img)
    
cv2.imshow('Maze', img)
    
    
# Binary conversion
    
    
img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img,15,55,55)#
    
    
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
# Inverting thresholding will give us a binary image with a white wall and a black background.
    
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 5, 4) 
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,filename1+' 1. Threshold1.jpg'), thresh)

# Contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
dc = cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, 0, (255, 255, 255), 5)
dc = cv2.bilateralFilter(dc,9,75,75)#

    
dc = cv2.drawContours(dc, contours, 1, (0,0,0) , 5)
dc = cv2.bilateralFilter(dc,9,75,75)#

    
#dc = cv2.blur(dc,(5,5))#
#ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dc, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(dc, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 5, 4)

    
    
ke = 19
kernel = np.ones((ke, ke), np.uint8)
    
# Dilate
    
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

    
# Erosion
    
    
erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=1) 
# Find differences between two images
diff = cv2.absdiff(dilation, erosion)

    
# splitting the channels of maze
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(diff)

    
# In order to display the solution on the original maze image, first divide the original maze into r, g, b components.
# Now create a mask by inverting the diff image.
# The bitwise and r and g components of the original maze using the mask created in the last step.
# This step will remove the red and green components from the image portion of the maze solution.
# The last one is to merge all the components and we will use the blue marked solution.
    
# masking out the green and red colour from the solved path
r = cv2.bitwise_and(r, r, mask=mask_inv)
b = cv2.bitwise_and(b, b, mask=mask_inv)
    
res = cv2.merge((b, g, r))
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,filename1+' 9. SolvedMaze.jpg'), res)
cv2.imshow('Solved Maze', res)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I modified the algorithm I've found here: https://github.com/ahnv/MazeSolver/tree/master. When I tested my modifications with the .png's, it works really well. However the performance on webcam pictures are hit or miss. The changes I made are, applying adaptive gaussian thresholding to make the light condiitons more even along the picture, and adding bilateral filtering. When you look at the examples on github, you could see that before applying dilation and erosion the solution would appear. In my case I fail to seperate the two halves after finding contours and applying thresholding. In the end, I can sometimes produce a perfect solution, or find all of the available path between the walls. Do I need to make the walls of the images sharper? I have avoided doing that since some unwanted information could also stand out more.
[this is the webcam picture I take](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3txw.jpg)